# Movement of electrons

Tags: electric-fields, potential

I do not understand why people say that electrons move from high to low potential, the potential of an electron due to a proton is given by $\frac{-Kq}{r}$ where $r$ is the distance from the proton. Now, naturally the electron will get attracted to the proton and lets suppose it gets to a distance $r_1$ where $r_1$ is less than r. Now as $r_1$ is less than r $\frac{Kq}{r_1}$ will be greater than  $\frac{Kq}{r_1}$ and so negative of both the sign will change so are not electrons travelling from High to low potential?

Comment: who says that electrons travel from high to low potential?? it was for positively charged particles not electrons

Comment: This is a language problem. Potential and potential energy are sometimes used synonymously although they are different concepts in EM. Objects typically feel a force that accelerates an object in the direction of lower potential energy. The same goes for an electron. It is pushed towards lower potential energy.  The potential energy is given by charge times electric potential. Electrons have a negative signed charge so the potential and the potential energy are different in sign. Thus it moves to lower potential energy which is equivalent to moving to a higher potential.

Comment: @maverick he just proved it

Comment: What do u mean by -"Potential of an electron due to proton"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First of all the potential  due to proton at some distance $R$ is given by $\cfrac{Kq}{R}$ not  $-\cfrac{Kq}{R}$ as you have mentioned.
2. Now since the proton would attract the electron towards itself, you could see $R$ would decrease it means,  the electron moves from low to high potential